# Cálculo de distância em C

Tags: c

A questão pede para calcular a menor distância entre as cidades. Foi dada a coordenada geográfica de cada região.

A saída correta seria:
1646.3
189.9

A minha saída apresentou valor incorreto no segundo cálculo:
1646.3
181.1

Link do problema do URI: 
https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1270

Código:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define INFINITO 100000000

struct cidade {
    char nome[15];
    int numRoteadores;
    int *coord_x;
    int *coord_y;
};

typedef struct cidade *Cidade;

Cidade newCidade(char nome[15], int numRoteadores) {  
    Cidade cidade = (Cidade) malloc(sizeof *cidade);  
    strcpy(cidade->nome, nome);  
    cidade->numRoteadores = numRoteadores;  
    cidade->coord_x = (int *) malloc(numRoteadores * sizeof(int));  
    cidade->coord_y = (int *) malloc(numRoteadores * sizeof(int));  

    return cidade;  
}  

int main() {
    int numCidades = -1;

    while(numCidades != 0){
        scanf("%d", &numCidades);

        if(numCidades >= 1 && numCidades <= 1000) {
            Cidade cidades[numCidades];
            char nomCidade;
            int numRoteadores;

            for(int i = 0; i < numCidades; i++){
                char nome[15];
                int numRoteadores;

                scanf("%s", nome);
                scanf("%d", &numRoteadores);

                cidades[i] = newCidade(nome, numRoteadores);

                for(int j = 0; j < numRoteadores; j++){
                    int coord_x, coord_y;

                    scanf("%d", &coord_x);
                    scanf("%d", &coord_y);

                    cidades[i]->coord_x[j] = coord_x;
                    cidades[i]->coord_y[j] = coord_y;
                }
            }

            float distTotal = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < numCidades - 1; i++){
                char nome1[15];
                char nome2[15];
                Cidade cidade1;
                Cidade cidade2;

                scanf("%s", nome1);
                scanf("%s", nome2);

                int j = 0;
                int achou = 0;
                while(achou < 2){
                    if(strcmp(cidades[j]->nome, nome1) == 0 || strcmp(cidades[j]->nome, nome2) == 0){
                        if(achou == 0){
                            cidade1 = cidades[j];
                            achou++;
                        }else{
                            cidade2 = cidades[j];
                            achou++;
                        }

                    }
                    j++;
                }
                float dist = INFINITO;
                //Acredito que o problema esteja aqui, onde a distância é calculada
                for(int k = 0; k < cidade1->numRoteadores; k++){
                    for(int l = 0; l < cidade2->numRoteadores; l++){
                        float newDist = sqrt(pow((cidade2->coord_x[l] - cidade1->coord_x[k] ),2) + pow((cidade2->coord_y[l] - cidade1->coord_y[k]),2));
                        if(newDist < dist){
                            dist = newDist;
                        }
                    }
                }

                distTotal += dist;
            }

            printf("%.1f\n", distTotal);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A pergunta está demasiado vaga. Comece por colocar por palavras suas o que é relevante do enunciado do exercicio, para quem quer responder não ter que ler o enunciado todo para perceber o contexto. Depois detalhe a parte especifica do código que não está a funcionar  caso contrário fica complicado a pessoa ter que navegar no seu código todo so para corrigir uma parte especifica. Esse detalhe deve incluir o que está errado, porque está  errado e como ficaria certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a [Fórmula de Haversine](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Haversine) para calcular a distancia entre duas coordenadas geográficas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue um código em `C` (testado) capaz de calcular a distância em quilômetros entre duas coordenadas geográficas:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define RAIO_GLOBO_TERRESTRE_KM  (6371)

double calcular_distancia( double th1, double ph1, double th2, double ph2 )
{
    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    double z = 0.0;

    ph1 -= ph2;
    ph1 *= M_PI / 180.0,
    th1 *= M_PI / 180.0,
    th2 *= M_PI / 180.0;

    z = sin(th1) - sin(th2);
    x = cos(ph1) * cos(th1) - cos(th2);
    y = sin(ph1) * cos(th1);

    return asin( sqrt( x * x + y * y + z * z) / 2.0) * 2.0 * RAIO_GLOBO_TERRESTRE_KM;
}


int main( void )
{
    double d = 0.0;

    d = calcular_distancia( -23.5489, -46.6388,    //Sao Paulo
                            -22.9035, -43.2096 );  //Rio de Janeiro

    printf("Sao Paulo x Rio de Janeiro: %.1f Km\n", d );


    d = calcular_distancia( -15.7801, -47.9292,    //Brasilia
                            -30.0277, -51.2287 );  //Porto Alegre

    printf("Brasilia x Porto Alegre: %.1f Km\n", d );

    return 0;
}
```

Compilando:

```
$ gcc -lm haversine.c -o haversine
```

Saída:

```
Sao Paulo x Rio de Janeiro: 357.7 Km
Brasilia x Porto Alegre: 1619.6 Km
```

Comment: O problema fala para usar distância euclidiana...

Answer (score 0):

No trecho:

```
float newDist = sqrt(pow((cidade2->coord_x[l] - cidade1->coord_x[k] ),2) + pow((cidade2->coord_y[l] - cidade1->coord_y[k]),2));
```

As variáveis coord são todas inteiras mas o resultado está sendo tratado como float.

Você vai ter problemas aqui, ou você trabalha com todos inteiros ou trabalha com todos float.

Este tipo de conversão em C é absurdamente problemático.

Comment: Fiz essa alteração e o resultado continuou o mesmo

Comment: Experimente trocar as variáveis de float pra double. Suspeito ser erro de arredondamento do float.